# Animating CollectionView cells like iOS Photos app Years/Months/Days picker?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I can't understand what Apple is using here in the iOS Photos collection view.

How do they transition the collection view when using the `Years / Months / Days / All Photos` segmented control?

Custom `CollectionViewFlowLayout`? Or custom transition between two CollectionViews (from "Years" to "Months" and back)?

[image: iOS 13 Photo app]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with using snapshots and animate them.

Comment: What do you mean by snapshots? DiffableDataSources? or image/screen shot snapshots?